# Pythonic way to create all the combinations from dictionary key to it's value's value

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-itertools

So let's say I have a dictionary like this:

```py
d = {"key1": (1, 2, 3), "key2": ("3", "4", "5")}
```

What I want to achieve (without nested looping, in a truly Pythonic way) is to get all the key-value combinations in this fashion:

```py
[("key1", 1), ("key1", 2), ("key1", 3), ("key2", "3"), ("key2", "4"), ("key2", "5")]
```

So like the combinations of key's assigned value values, since the value will be a container.

I tried going through `itertools` docs, but I didn't seem to find anything to help me with this. Is there any way to do this nicely, or am I to use loops?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A nested list comprehension does the trick:

```
d = {"key1": (1, 2, 3), "key2": ("3", "4", "5")}
result = [(k,v) for k,values in d.items() for v in values]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[('key1', 1), ('key1', 2), ('key1', 3), ('key2', '3'), ('key2', '4'), ('key2', '5')]
```

Comment: Ahh, that simple. Well, instead of trying to find a lib-based solution, I should go for the beauty of python container comprehensions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `itertools` solution isn't as nice as the comprehension method but it is still possible.

```
from itertools import chain, product

list(chain.from_iterable(product([k], v) for k, v in d.items()))

[('key2', '3'),
 ('key2', '4'),
 ('key2', '5'),
 ('key1', 1),
 ('key1', 2),
 ('key1', 3)]
```

Comment: That's still a possibility to consider, thanks as well!